# How to write a null hypothesis using the ntheorem package

Tags: ntheorem

I have two hypotheses. One effect hypothesis (number 1), and a null hypothesis (number 2). How do I make the null hypothesis appear as Hypothesis 0 instead of Hypothesis 2?

I.e. I want to change the numbering of the hypotheses without changing the order that they appear in the tex file

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{ntheorem} % For writing hypotheses 
\theoremseparator{:} % Insert :
\newtheorem{hyp}{Hypothesis} % Name "Hypothesis" 

\begin{document}

\begin{hyp}
My first hypothesis   
\end{hyp}

\begin{hyp}
My null hypothesis   
\end{hyp}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My impression is that you don't want automatic numbering.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem} % For writing hypotheses
\theoremseparator{:} % Insert :

\newtheorem*{hyp*}{Hypothesis \protect\hypnumber} % Name "Hypothesis"
\newenvironment{hyp}[1]{\renewcommand{\hypnumber}{#1}\begin{hyp*}}{\end{hyp*}}
\newcommand{\hypnumber}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{hyp}{1}
My first hypothesis
\end{hyp}

\begin{hyp}{0}
My null hypothesis
\end{hyp}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could set the counter to -1 before the null hypothesis (which will increase it to 0) and then back 1 afterwards:

```
\setcounter{hyp}{-1}
\begin{hyp}
My null hypothesis   
\end{hyp}
\setcounter{hyp}[1}
```

That could be inconvenient however if you ever move the placement of the null hypothesis relative to other hypotheses, since you'd then have to set it back to something else.

An alternative would just to introduce a second nullhyp environment so its counter wouldn't interfere with the main hyp counter, so you wouldn't have to reset it afterwards.

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{ntheorem} % For writing hypotheses 
\theoremseparator{:} % Insert :
\newtheorem{hyp}{Hypothesis} % Name "Hypothesis" 
\newtheorem{nullhyp}{Hypothesis} % Same name, different counter

\begin{document}

\begin{hyp}
My first hypothesis   
\end{hyp}

\setcounter{nullhyp}{-1}
\begin{nullhyp}
My null hypothesis   
\end{nullhyp}

\begin{hyp}
My next hypothesis   
\end{hyp}


\end{document}
```

I'm sure there are other methods.